# How properly exclude files in Git hooks?

Tags: git, githooks

Currently I have `post-receive` hook which looks like this

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/project --git-dir=/var/repos/Project.git checkout -f
```

Is it possible to exclude/ignore few folders?

I need the following local folders to be excluded when the hook executes:

- /var/www/project/app/config/local
- /var/www/project/bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pathspec with exclusions.

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/project --git-dir=/var/repos/Project.git checkout -f -- ':/:*' ':!/:app/config/local' ':!/:bootstrap'
```

Comment: Did you remember the `:/:*' (and note that this argument does *not* use a `!`)?  I've retested and this does work, assuming there's anything outside the excluded directories.  The most likely way for it to fail would be an error with command syntax